# error while trying to use rviz to visualize the urdf

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to use the rviz package to visualize the urdf I had made using a launch file

but every time I am trying to roslaunch my launch file give me this error

I have double checked every thing but the error still appear

```
 roslaunch mastering_ros_robot_description_pkg view_demo.launch
[view_demo.launch] is neither a launch file in package [mastering_ros_robot_description_pkg] nor is [mastering_ros_robot_description_pkg] a launch file name
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/270039/error-while-trying-to-use-rviz-to-visualize-the-urdf/) by [ShehabAldeen](https://answers.ros.org/users/31455/shehabaldeen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 97 on 2017-09-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try out the answer to #q143496 or any of the other many questions containing the phrase 'is neither a launch file in package'.

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2017-09-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1